# JSON response: Spring with JAXB

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb, resteasy

Tech Stack: Java 1.6, JAXB, Spring 3, JAX-RS (RESTEasy), XSD

Hello,

I am using Spring with JAX-RS to create RestFul Webservice.

Everything is working fine except that the generated responses contain the setters info e.g.

```
  {
    ...

    "setName": true,
    "setId": true,
    "setAddress": true,
    "setAge": true,
}
```

I don't know what might be causing this?
How can I turn this off?

Adi

**UPDATE 1:**

The PersonRequest class is generated by the JAXB and contains all the javax.xml.bind.annotation.* annotations.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "personResponse " })
@XmlRootElement(name = "PersonResponse ")
public class PersonResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "Id", required = true)
    protected String id;

    // and the setters and getters



}
```

and the Resource looks like this:

```
@Component
@Path("/person")
public class PersonImpl implements Person {

    @Override
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, "application/x-amf" })
    @Path("v1")
    public PersonResponse getPerson() {

       ....
       ....
    }


}
```

** UPDATE 2 **
This happens only when Content-Type is json, in case of Content Type as 'xml', the setters are not returned. If that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't that `propOrder` be `{ "name", "id" }` rather than `{ "personResponse " }`?

Comment: yes, maybe. These beans are autogenerated and created this sample only for advice. I didnt posted the original code as it was too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the xjb file, for details look in the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860742/jaxb-bean-generation).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some other part of the stack is weaving in extra fields to your domain model (I.e some ORM libraries do this).  To confirm you could use the `java.lang.reflect` APIs to see what fields your class has after it had been loaded by the `ClassLoader`.