# JAXB Bean Generation

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, schema

I am using JAXB for generating beans from XSD's using a JAXB plugin in Maven.
This is working fine, expect that the code contains isSetXXXXXX() methods for each field.

e.g.

for a field **firstName**, it is producing the following code:

```
@XmlElement(name = "FirstName", required = true)
    protected String firstName;

  public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.token = firstName;
    }

    public boolean isSetFirstName() {
        return (this.firstName!= null);
    }
```

This isSetFirstName() method is causing issues and I don't want JAXB to generate these.

**Is there a way to stop this behaviour?**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Solved this: Problem was in the xjb file, generateIsSetMethod was set to true.

```
<xs:annotation>
   <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">

      bindingStyle="modelGroupBinding"
         choiceContentProperty="true" >

           <xjc:serializable uid="12343"/>
           <jaxb:javaType name="short" 
              xmlType="xs:long" 
              printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printShort"   
              parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseShort"/>

      </jaxb:globalBindings>
   </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

And this answered my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620450/json-response-spring-with-jaxb) as well.

Comment: Hey adi, your updated XML snippet isn't valid XML, is the > after `generateIsSetMethod="true"` meant to be there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will not generate `isSet` methods.  Since you are getting them one of the following must be true:

1. You can a schema annotation that specifies:  `<jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true"/>`
2. You have an external binding file that specifies:  `<jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true"/>`
3. You are specifying a property to the Maven plug-in to generate the `isSet` methods.

Comment: Though I answered my question before you answered, but still this is correct and informative answer, so a big yes.